# Need help for create the test class

Tags: unit-test, class

I'm a new developer and it's my first test class. I need your help to do it the class test for my helper class.

HELP ME PLEASE!!

```
    @isTest
public class TestOrderWizardHelper {
    static testMethod void notAvailableQuotaTest() {   
        List<String> listIdPromo = new List<String>();
        Map<String, Boolean> mapAvailableQuota = new Map<String, Boolean>();
        if(listIdPromo != null){
            List<PromoRep__c> figuraPromo = new List<PromoRep__c>();
            List<PromoGeographyB2B__c> listGeoPromo = new List<PromoGeographyB2B__c>();
            figuraPromo = [Select Id,User__c,PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c,AssignedQuota__c,ConsumedQuantity__c,Available_Quota__c,PromoB2B__r.Apply_boxes_with_charge__c from PromoRep__c where User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId() and PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c in :listIdPromo LIMIT 1000];
            Set<String> setHierarchyReg = new Set<String>();
            List<GeographicCoverage__c> listAuxGeoCover = [SELECT ZoneCode__r.ParentCode__r.ParentCode__r.Id FROM GeographicCoverage__c WHERE RepAndZone__r.RepCode__c = :([Select roleCode__c from User where Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1].roleCode__c)];
            for(GeographicCoverage__c gc : listAuxGeoCover){
                setHierarchyReg.add(gc.ZoneCode__r.ParentCode__r.ParentCode__r.Id);
            }
            listGeoPromo = [Select Id,PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c,AssignedQuota__c,ConsumedQuantity__c,Hierarchy__c,PromoB2B__r.Apply_boxes_with_charge__c From PromoGeographyB2B__c where PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c in : listIdPromo and Hierarchy__c in :setHierarchyReg limit 5000];
        }
            Test.startTest();
            OrderWizardHelper.notAvailableQuotaTest(mapAvailableQuota[0].Id);
            Test.stopTest();
    }
    static testMethod void hasAvailableQuotaOpportunityTest() {    
        Boolean resultado = false;
        List<String> opp = new List<String>();
        Id dotacionIdRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.PromoB2B__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Provisioning').getRecordTypeId();
        List<OrderLineB2B__c> listOrderLine = new List<OrderLineB2B__c>();
        Map<String,PromoRep__c> mapPromoFiguraPromo = new Map<String,PromoRep__c>();
        PromoRep__c auxPromoRep = new PromoRep__c();
        Set<String> setIdsPromos = new Set<String>();

        listOrderLine = [Select Id,billed__c,promo__c,PromoB2B__c,PromoB2B__r.RecordTypeId from OrderLineB2B__c where Order__c = :opp.Id and PromoB2B__r.RecordTypeId = :dotacionIdRecordType];
        Test.startTest();
        OrderWizardHelper.hasAvailableQuotaOpportunityTest(resultado);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    static testMethod void restaCupoDotacionTest() { 
        List<String> opp = new List<String>();
        Id dotacionIdRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.PromoB2B__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Provisioning').getRecordTypeId();
        List<OrderLineB2B__c> linesOrder = [Select Id,promo__c,billed__c,Order__c,PromoB2B__c from OrderLineB2B__c where Order__c =:opp.Id and PromoB2B__c!= null and PromoB2B__r.RecordTypeId =:dotacionIdRecordType];
        Set<String> setIdsPromos = new Set<String>();

        Map<String,PromoRep__c> mapFigurasPromos = new Map<String,PromoRep__c>();

        Map<String,PromoGeographyB2B__c>mapGeoPromos = new Map<String,PromoGeographyB2B__c>();
        Map<String,PromoProductB2B__c> mapProductPromo = new Map<String,PromoProductB2B__c>();
        PromoRep__c auxPromoRep = new PromoRep__c();
        PromoProductB2B__c auxPromoProd = new PromoProductB2B__c();
        PromoGeographyB2B__c auxPromoGeo = new PromoGeographyB2B__c();
        Map<String,PromoRep__c> toUpdatePromoRep = new Map<String,PromoRep__c>();
        Map<String,PromoProductB2B__c> toUpdatePromoProd = new Map<String,PromoProductB2B__c>();
        Map<String,PromoGeographyB2B__c> toUpdatePromoGeo = new Map<String,PromoGeographyB2B__c>();

        Test.startTest();
        OrderWizardHelper.restaCupoDotacionTest(toUpdatePromoGeo);
        Test.stopTest();  
    }
    static testMethod void recalculteIdQuotaInOrderLine() {  
        Set<String> setPromoSel = new Set<String>();
        Map<Id,Id> mapIdUserIdQuota = new Map<Id,Id>();
        List<PromoRep__c> listPromoRep = new List<PromoRep__c>();
        LiST<PromoGeographyB2B__c> listPromoGeo = new List<PromoGeographyB2B__c>();
        Set<String> setHierarchyReg = calculateHierarchyRegUser();
        listPromoRep = [Select Id,User__c from PromoRep__c where PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c in :setPromoSel and User__c = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
        listPromoGeo = [Select Id from PromoGeographyB2B__c where PromoB2B__r.CodPromo__c in :setPromoSel and  Hierarchy__c in :setHierarchyReg];
        Test.startTest();
        OrderWizardHelper.recalculteIdQuotaInOrderLine(setPromoSel[0].Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    static testMethod void calculateHierarchyRegUserTest() {    
        Set<String> setHierarchyReg = new Set<String>();
        List<GeographicCoverage__c> listAuxGeoCover = [SELECT ZoneCode__r.ParentCode__r.ParentCode__r.Id FROM GeographicCoverage__c WHERE RepAndZone__r.RepCode__c = :([Select roleCode__c from User where Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1].roleCode__c)];
        for(GeographicCoverage__c gc : listAuxGeoCover){
            setHierarchyReg.add(gc.ZoneCode__r.ParentCode__r.ParentCode__r.Id);
        }   
        Test.startTest();
        OrderWizardHelper.calculateHierarchyRegUser(setHierarchyReg[0].ZoneCode__r.ParentCode__r.ParentCode__r.Id);
        Test.stopTest();   
    }
    static testMethod void sendEmailOrderBlocked() {  
        List<String> opp = new List<String>();
        blob body;
        PageReference htmlPage = page.VF_Email_Order_Block;
        body = htmlPage.getContent();
        String htmlBody = body.toString();
        Opportunity newOpp = [Select Id,ExternalId__c FROM Opportunity where id = :opp.Id limit 1];
        String bodyHtml = htmlBody;
        String bodyRepeat = bodyHtml.substring(bodyHtml.indexOf('!repeatIni') + 10,bodyHtml.indexOf('!repeatFin'));
        String auxBodyRepeat = '';
        UserRole parentRole = [SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole WHERE Id in (Select UserRoleId from User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId())];
        User managerUser = [Select Id, Name,Email  from User where UserRoleId = :parentRole.ParentRoleId limit 1 ]; 
        List<OrderLineB2B__c> listLines = [Select IdProduct__c,ProdName__c ,Id,billed__c,promo__c,Figura_Promocional__r.Available_Quota__c ,Geografia_Promocional__r.AssignedQuota__c,Geografia_Promocional__r.ConsumedQuantity__c, Figura_Promocional__c,Geografia_Promocional__c  from OrderLineB2B__c where Order__c =: opp.Id and BloquedItem__c = true];
        Set<String> setCodProd = new Set<String>();
        for(OrderLineB2B__c oline : listLines){
            setCodProd.add(oline.IdProduct__c);
        }
        Map<String,Product2> mapProductCodName = new Map<String,Product2>();
        for(Product2 prod : [Select Id,ExternalId__c,Name FROM Product2 WHERE ExternalId__c in : setCodProd]){
            mapProductCodName.put(prod.ExternalId__c, prod);
        }
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!User.Manager', managerUser.Name);
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!User.Name', UserInfo.getName());
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!Opportunity.Id', newOpp.Id);
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!Opportunity.ExternalId__c', newOpp.ExternalId__c);
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!URL__c','https://zamoracompany--atosdevsb.cs100.my.salesforce.com/00O1x000000JSPsEAO');

        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.remove('!repeatFin');
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.remove(bodyRepeat);

        for(OrderLineB2B__c line : listLines){
            auxBodyRepeat = auxBodyRepeat + '<br/>' + bodyRepeat;
            auxBodyRepeat = auxBodyRepeat.replace('!Product2.Name', mapProductCodName.get(line.IdProduct__c).Name);
            auxBodyRepeat = auxBodyRepeat.replace('!OrderLineB2B__c.billed__c', String.valueOf(line.billed__c + line.promo__c));
            auxBodyRepeat = auxBodyRepeat.replace('!PromoRep__c.Available_Quota__c', line.Figura_Promocional__c != null ? String.valueOf(line.Figura_Promocional__r.Available_Quota__c) : line.Geografia_Promocional__c != null ? String.valueOf(line.Geografia_Promocional__r.AssignedQuota__c - line.Geografia_Promocional__r.ConsumedQuantity__c) : null);
            auxBodyRepeat = auxBodyRepeat + + '<br/>'; 
        }
        bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace('!repeatIni',auxBodyRepeat);

        Test.startTest();
        OrderWizardHelper.sendEmailOrderBlocked(new List<String>{UserInfo.getUserEmail(),managerUser.Email},bodyHtml, 'Pedido bloqueado nยบ ' + newOpp.ExternalId__c, null);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gonazlo, Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour], I have marked your question as a duplicate, since this is a very common questions. The link contains the necessary resources and links to help you get started. Thanks